# How to find out permissions for each tree element(folder or file) for another user using sharepoint api?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-api

I want to get answer for question:

> Does **userA** can read the folder/tree ?

Application uses another user to communicate with sharpoint via sharepoint API.

I've googled the following request:

```
http://aissp2013/sites/Team/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('L2')/EffectiveBasePermissions
```

But it doesn't resolve my problem because it responds with permissions for current user!

1. Is there way to get permissions for another user for concrete element(folder or file or library)
2. Is there way to get permissions for another user for all elements and **sub-elements** ?

Answer (score 2):

To get permissions *per user* [`SP.ListItem.getUserEffectivePermissions` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850758.aspx) is intended:

for `SP.Folder`

```
Url /_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<folder-rel-url>')/ListItemAllFields/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='<account>'
Method: Get
```

for `SP.File`

```
Url /_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file-rel-url>')/ListItemAllFields/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='<account>'
Method: Get
```

> Note: `account` parameter needs to be provided in [claims format](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-20102013-claims-encoding.aspx)

Regarding the question:

> Does userA can read the folder/tree ?

the following example demonstrates how to retrieve permissions for a folder

```
 const accountName = "i:0#.f|membership|<name>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com"; 

  let endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Achive')/ListItemAllFields/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'";
  const content = await executeJson(endpointUrl);

  let roles = parseBasePermissions(content.d.GetUserEffectivePermissions);
  if(roles.viewListItems)
     console.log(`${accountName} has been granted permissions.`);
```

where

```
function parseBasePermissions(value)
{      
    let permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
    permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(value);
    let result = {};
    for(var levelName in SP.PermissionKind.prototype) {
        if (SP.PermissionKind.hasOwnProperty(levelName)) {
            var permLevel = SP.PermissionKind.parse(levelName);
            if(permissions.has(permLevel))
                result[levelName] = true;
            else
                result[levelName] = false;
        }     
    }
    return result; 
}
```

is used to parse permission mask into roles

and

```
async function executeJson(url,options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.method = options.method || 'GET';
    options.headers = options.headers || {};
    options.headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        options.headers["X-RequestDigest"] = document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value;
    }    
    if (options.body) {
       options.body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
    }  
    const rawResponse = await fetch(url,options);
    const content = await rawResponse.json();
    return content;
}
```

to perform REST request

Comment: thank you - fantastic answer.But I have one additional question.  If I understand your answer correct - the request you provided allow me to find out permissions for concrete folder or file. In my case it is  not convenient because I need to know permissions for each element in tree. It is not a good idea to  execute rest call for each element in library because of  performance. Is there way to execute single rest call to find out permissions for full tree ?

Comment: also I use java to communicate with sharepoint, so I don't have a javascript object SP.PermissionKind to parse permissions